# Cannot locate any parts of the body of an element with selenium for python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, screen-scraping

Life has been tough on me lately. I have tried to scrape a website (https://osf.io/preprints/discover?subject=bepress%7CSocial%20and%20Behavioral%20Sciences) with some of the HTML code below for a week now and have tried multiple things to get it to work. I need the div ID `ember499` all the way at the bottom. This div is the one that contains the whole website, and if I cant access it, I cant scrape anything. There are 4 divs in the main body tag, `MaxJax_Message`, `ember-bootstrap-wormhole`, `ember-basic-dropdown-wormhole` and `ember499` as seen below:

```html
<body class="ember-application">
<div id="MathJax_Message" style="display: none;"></div>
    <noscript>
        <p>
        For full functionality of this site it is necessary to enable JavaScript.
        Here are
            <a href='https://www.enable-javascript.com/' target='_blank'> instructions for enabling JavaScript in your web browser</a>.
        </p>
    </noscript>

    <script> window.prerenderReady = false; </script>

    

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/2.18.0/ember.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        (function() {
            var encodedConfig = document.head.querySelector("meta[name$='/config/environment']").content;
            var config = JSON.parse(unescape(encodedConfig));
            var assetSuffix = config.ASSET_SUFFIX ? '-' + config.ASSET_SUFFIX : '';
            var origin = window.location.origin;
            window.isProviderDomain = !~config.OSF.url.indexOf(origin);
            var prefix = '/' + (window.isProviderDomain ? '' : 'preprints/') + 'assets/';
            [
                'vendor',
                'preprint-service'
            ].forEach(function (name) {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = prefix + name + assetSuffix + '.js';
                script.async = false;
                document.body.appendChild(script);

                var link = document.createElement('link');
                link.rel = 'stylesheet';
                link.href = prefix + name + assetSuffix + '.css';
                document.head.appendChild(link);
            });
        })();
    </script><script src="/preprints/assets/vendor-f46d275519d6cf7078493fc4564ccd3c7dc419ed.js"></script><script src="/preprints/assets/preprint-service-f46d275519d6cf7078493fc4564ccd3c7dc419ed.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.ravenjs.com/3.22.1/ember/raven.min.js"></script>
                    <script>
                        var encodedConfig = document.head.querySelector("meta[name$='/config/environment']").content;
                        var config = JSON.parse(unescape(encodedConfig));
                        if (config.sentryDSN) {
                            Raven.config(config.sentryDSN, config.sentryOptions || {}).install();
                        }
                    </script>

    <div id="ember-basic-dropdown-wormhole"></div>
<div id="ember-bootstrap-wormhole"></div>
  

<div id="ember499" class="ember-view">
<!---->

    <div id="ember538" class="__new-osf-navbar__b7554 ember-view"><div class="osf-nav-wrapper">
    <nav id="navbarScope" role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="/" aria-label="Go home" class="navbar-brand">
                    <span class="osf-navbar-logo"></span>
                </a>

                <div class="service-name">
                    <a href="https://osf.io/preprints/">
                        <span class="hidden-xs"> OSF </span>
```

I have tried printing all of the divs that are contained in the main body for example:

```py3
wormhole = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ember-application')
divs = wormhole.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'div')
```

I have tried finding via `XPATH`, `ID`, more or less everything. When I print the ID of each div and append it into a list I get this:
`['MathJax_Message', 'ember-basic-dropdown-wormhole', 'ember-bootstrap-wormhole']`
Funnily enough, when I print `len(divs)` i get 3 back, but when I dont append them into a list it takes an extra 2-3 seconds to finish executing once it reaches `div[3]`, this generally does not tend to happen with other sites:

```
OUTPUT

MathJax_Message
ember-basic-dropdown-wormhole
ember-bootstrap-wormhole

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have tried scrolling to the middle of the page in case its hidden, finding out what is in each of the 3 divs above it, going directly to the class names that I want, finding all elements of the webpage using `find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*')`. They all either only return the same 3 divs mentioned above, or they say 'element not found'. I cant think of what else to do/try.

Please guide me Stack Gods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide `delay` time.sleep()

```
driver.get('https://osf.io/preprints/discover?subject=bepress%7CSocial%20and%20Behavioral%20Sciences')
time.sleep(5)
print(len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".ember-application div")))
for ele in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".ember-application div"):
    print(ele.text)
```

Output:

```
275



OSF PREPRINTS
Add a Preprint
Search
Support
Donate
Sign Up Sign In
Preprint Archive Search
powered by
Search
2,365,609 searchable as of November 01, 2022
Partner Repositories
Previous
Next
Sort by: Relevance
Active Filters:
Clear filters
Social and Behavioral Sciences
Refine your search by
Providers
OSF Preprints (50,302)
AfricArXiv (394)
AgriXiv (426)
Arabixiv (328)
arXiv (1,324,846)
BioHackrXiv (29)
bioRxiv (48,109)
BodoArXiv (110)
Cogprints (283)
CoP (1)
EarthArXiv (1,755)
EcoEvoRxiv (940)
ECSarXiv (241)
EdArXiv (1,088)
engrXiv (2,088)
FocUS Archive (52)
Frenxiv (148)
INA-Rxiv (16,605)
IndiaRxiv (148)
LawArXiv (1,374)
LIS Scholarship Archive (310)
MarXiv (456)
MediArXiv (201)
MetaArXiv (457)
MindRxiv (286)
NutriXiv (84)
PaleorXiv (219)
PeerJ (4,747)
Preprints.org (21,880)
PsyArXiv (25,458)
RePEc (848,335)
SocArXiv (11,629)
SportRxiv (386)
Thesis Commons (1,857)
Subject
Architecture
Arts and Humanities
Business
Education
Engineering
Law
Life Sciences
Medicine and Health Sciences
Physical Sciences and Mathematics
Social and Behavioral Sciences
Do you want to add your own research as a preprint?
Add a preprint
The Corporate Social Responsibility is just a twist in a M\"obius Strip
Solferino, NazariaSolferino, Viviana
Last edited: Oct 13, 2015 UTC
Finance Social and Behavioral Sciences Economics
In recent years economics agents and systems have became more and more interacting and juxtaposed, therefore the social sciences need to rely on the studies of physical sciences to analyze this complexity in the relationships. According to this point of view we rely on the geometrical model of the M ...
arXiv
Some suggestions on dealing with measurement error in linkage analyses
Marko BachlMichael Scharkow
Last edited: Jul 2, 2018 UTC
Social and Behavioral Sciences Communication
Linkage analysis is a sophisticated media effect research design that reconstructs the likely exposure to relevant media messages of individual survey respondents by complementing the survey data with a content analysis. It is an important improvement over survey-only designs: Instead of predicting ...
OSF Preprints
Imagined Interdependence: Manipulating Discourse Changes How People Construe Interdependence
Jiří Münich..so on
```

Comment: Thank you, seems I just needed to wait a little!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the div you are trying to grab has `id` which changes every time you load page. So to grab that particular div you have to use `XPATH` (you can use any other selector also if you want, but i prefer `XPATH`).

Please find the code below, Let me know if you have any query.

```
driver.get("https://osf.io/preprints/discover?subject=bepress%7CSocial%20and%20Behavioral%20Sciences")
ember = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@class="ember-application"]/div[contains(@id,"ember") and @class="ember-view"]')))

print(ember.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

You should also use **explicit wait** to get your desired HTML element. `time.sleep()` is not advisable as it may only halt the process for a time being without realizing whether the element is appeared or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How did you know that the id changes though?

Comment: Because if you refresh the page it is changing. In yours it is showing 499 in mine it showing 538. Did my code solves your problem?